# Is this a valid proof that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the following polynomial $P(x) = x^2 - 3$.
By the rational root theorem, the only possible rational roots are $\pm{3}$ or $\pm{1}$. Substituting these into $P(x)$ gives $6$ and $-2$, respectively. Thus $P(x)$ has no rational roots. Thus $\sqrt{3}$ is not rational.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138065/discussion-on-question-by-nostradamus-is-this-a-valid-proof-that-sqrt3-is-i).